# Interactive coordinate system for Angular 9

Tags: angular, plot, graph, frameworks, coordinates

i‘m looking for a interactive coordinate system framework (e.g. you click on x=4, y=-2 and create a dot, getting values with an event listener or similar) for Angular. It is for a school project, teaching students second & third degree functions.

Already tried plotly but its not exactly what I need. More something like GeoGebra (which does not work that good in Angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used embeddes Desmos graphs.

https://www.desmos.com